# Number of load instruction in a program

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-3.0

How to count total number of load instruction on a simple "hello world" program through LLVM ??

Comment: Do you want to count the number of load instructions that appear in the code, or the number of load instructions that will be performed when the code is ran?

Comment: I want to write a pass that counts the number of load instructions in the IR of "hello world" program........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a pass which iterates over all the instructions in the module, then count the number of instructions that fulfil `isa<LoadInst>(I)`.

See [the programmer's manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function) for how to iterate over all the instructions.

If you're not sure how to write a pass, take a look at [this handy guide](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html).